# How to use sans serif font in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, plain-tex, sans-serif, computer-modern

It is rather common to typeset theories (that is a set of statements) such as ZFC in a sans serif font family.
I tried the following:

```
\font\ss=ecss1000
\def\ZFC{\ss ZFC}

\ZFC

$\ZFC\models\exists X\forall x(x\not\in X)$

\bye
```

The first command correctly produces a sans-serif text but not the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\font\sstext=ecss1000
\font\sssub=ecss1000 at 7pt
\font\sssubsub=ecss1000 at 5pt

\newfam\ssfam
\textfont\ssfam=\sstext
\scriptfont\ssfam=\sssub
\scriptscriptfont\ssfam=\sssubsub

\def\ss{\fam\ssfam\sstext} % usually \sf as \ss is ß
\def\ZFC{\ss ZFC} % or more likely \def\ZFC{{\ss ZFC}}

\ZFC

$\ZFC\models\exists X\forall x(x\not\in X)$

\bye
```

Comment: You probably want `\def\ZFC{{\ss ZFC}}` so the font change is just for ZFC not the whole document but that isn't directly related to your question

Comment: Great thank you, so I should replace ss by sf everywhere (except in ecss1000 and so on) to be more idiomatic?

Comment: @atrst especially if you are German and want stra\ss e to be straße, but plain tex is an example format for small examples in the texbook, I would expect any format designed for typsetting documents would have this set up already

Comment: I occasionally write in German and forgot about that, thank you. I am just playing a bit with TeX, I am not planning to use this in a published book or something, just for my notes

Comment: @atrst I'd use latex not plain for notes.

Comment: I'd use OpTeX not plain nor LaTeX for notes.

Comment: @wipet yes or context even eplain